# the where statement from f90 to matlab conversion

Tags: matlab, fortran, conventions

This is a part from a Fortran 90 code.

```
where (abs(A-B)>e)
    no_converge=1
elsewhere
    no_converge=0
end where
```

A and B are arrays of some particular dimensions, and e is a scalar. I have to say that I am not that familiar with either programming languages.

I have used the `f2matlab` but it does very poor job on this Fortran statement.

I am wondering whether the equivalent for a Matlab is something like this:

```
if abs(A-B)>e
    no_converge=1 ;
else 
    no_converge=0 ; 
end
```

Is this correct ?

The no_converge is a scalar (`integer` in Fortran declarations), used at different sections in order to begin some other loops.

I will really appreciate any suggestions here, and please let me know whether more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not correct, no.  In the Fortran `no_converge` ought to be an array of the same size (and shape) as `A` and `B`; its elements will be set to `1` where `abs(A-B)>e` and `0` elsewhere.  So in your Matlab code `no_converge` shouldn't be a scalar but an array.  However, without sight of your declarations I'm just making educated guesses.  Show us some (more) code.

I don't have Matlab on this computer so can't check, but if memory serves me well you can do something very similar, like this

```
no_converge(abs(A-B)>e) = 1
no_converge(abs(A-B)<=e) = 0
```

provided that `no_converge` is, as in the Fortran case, an array of the same size and shape as `A` and `B`.

Comment: Thanks it works what you are suggesting me, and indeed the no_converge had to be of the same size as of A and B.

Answer (score 0):

The [`WHERE` statement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAT4T_10.1.0/com.ibm.xlf101l.doc/xlflr/where.htm%23where) in Fortran sort of combines a loop with a conditional, but only for *assignments*.

`no_convergence` in the Fortran code *must* be a vector with (at least) the same extend as `A` and `B`. So, the code you provided is certainly incorrect.

I don't know whether you can do something similar in Matlab, but you can always do a explicit loop and test for convergence element-wise.

Answer (score 0):

There WHERE construct in Fortran can be replaced by a MERGE one-liner which f2matlab may be better able to translate:

```
no_converge = merge(1,0,abs(A-B)>e)
```